# Are they already planning a successor to the JWST?

Tags: space-telescope, james-webb-telescope, future-missions

Hubble has been flying for 30+ years. JWST took 10 years to fund and build.

But given its 10 year (if we're lucky) life expectancy, I assume its successor is already on a drawing board somewhere.

Comment: Luvoir is a still a concept i think there arent any real plan

Comment: errata: jwst took 26 years to fund and build.

Comment: Arianespace recently shared that the launch was nominal and so JWST should be able to get the 10-12 years of service time instead of the minimum 6 if something went not completely nominally in the launch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the Launch Pad Astronomy video *4 Future Space Telescopes NASA wants to build* linked below.

The notes say that the four

> ...future space telescopes NASA wants to build are the:
>
> 1. [Habitable Exoplanet Explorer (HabEx)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitable_Exoplanet_Imaging_Mission)
> 2. the [Lynx X-Ray telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_X-ray_Observatory)
> 3. [Origins Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_Space_Telescope)
> 4. the [Large Ultraviolet Optical Infrared Explorer (LUVOIR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LUVOIR)
>
> If approved, these 4  future space telescopes will succeed the James Webb Space Telescope and the [Nancy Grace Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Grace_Roman_Space_Telescope) space telescopes.

Related:

- [The proposed LUVOIR space telescope can point at different targets while keeping the sunshade in a fixed orientation. How? What else moves?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57345/12102)