# Is there any point in space that the James Webb Space Telescope would be unable to image?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

The James Webb Space Telescope has some very specific positioning requirements; the second Lagrange point and the heat shield positioning being at the top of my mind.

[image]

Do these constraints eliminate the possibility of pointing the telescope at any general region of space? For example, a telescope positioned at the south pole can never image Polaris because Earth is always obstructing the view.

For the JWST at first I thought you could analogize this to "the belt of space always hidden behind the earth and the sun", but then I realized that part of space isn't *always* hidden, but it instead would simply be unavailable on a "rotating" basis depending on the time of year; after all what is hidden behind the sun in January is out the opposite direction during summer. But my astronomy foo is weak and I wonder if there are other aspects of the deployment and operation that could affect things that I'm unaware of.

Are there any portions of the sky that the JWST will never be able to image because of constraints on it's positioning?

Comment: It cannot image anything inside of its orbit. Earth, Venus, Mercury, etc are out. You probably realize this, but you may want to clarify. 

It also wont bother looking directly at Jupiter and Saturn, as it’s sensors would just be over exposed as I understand it. But technically it could when the orbits are right.

Comment: Oh interesting! In actuality, I _hadn't_ thought of that when composing the question, so I appreciate your commentary. It makes complete sense when taking into account that the telescope cannot aim _inwards_ as @Prometheus2508 explains in his answer.

Comment: @EricG answers to [Can James Webb take pictures of our solar system? In what ways will they differ from/compliment those from Hubble?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57492/12102) suggest that at some point JWST *might indeed* bother to look directly at Jupiter and Saturn, though it's not scheduled to do so in the first cycle as there are observations more fundamental to its *raison d'etre* to do first.

Comment: @uhoh - Thanks for the correction.  I apparently mis-remembered the line "The very large infrared brightnesses of Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn may limit Webb observations of these planets to a subset of the instrument modes" and in my head generalized to all instruments.

Comment: @EricG an opportunity for a new question, yay! [Which JWST instrument modes are compatible with observations of the bright outer planets Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn? Which aren't?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48131/7982)

Comment: @uhoh it actually *is* scheduled to [look at Jupiter](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1373.pdf) during its first 5 months, and then during the first general cycle is scheduled to look at [Jupiter again](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1246.pdf), [Mars](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1415.pdf), [Saturn](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1247.pdf), and for a bonus also [Uranus](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1248.pdf) and [Neptune](https://www.stsci.edu/jwst/phase2-public/1249.pdf).

Comment: Well, if we ever put another satellite at L1 or L3, then this theoretical satellite and James Webb at L2 clearly couldn't view each other...

Comment: What are you really Asking, Cory Klein?

Can it see behind itself? Can it see through objects? Can it see infinitely far? What else is there?

Comment: It's quite clear @CoryKlein, no? Are there any parts of the night sky which it will never (or rarely) be able to look at because the sun will always be in the way?

Comment: (In fact, it has already looked at Jupiter, as this [NASA blog post](https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2022/07/14/webb-images-of-jupiter-and-more-now-available-in-commissioning-data/) shows!)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Here's](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard) a really great article with pictures that explains it better than I can. But to summarize:

[image: JWST Observatory Coordinates diagram]

If you draw a line between the JWST and the Sun, it can point up to 5° towards the sun or 45° away from it while keeping all the sensitive parts shaded by the heat shield. In addition, it can rotate in any direction around that line. And (not really relevant to this question) it can roll up to about 5° side-to-side.

The net result of this is that

- At any given time, the telescope can see a lot of the sky, but not all of it. There's a 45° cone pointing away from the sun and an 85° cone pointing towards it that the telescope cannot image.
- Although the telescope cannot point directly towards or away from the sun, 3 months later the directions that were towards or away from the sun become perpendicular to the sun and can be imaged. As it completes its orbit around the sun, it's eventually able to see the entire sky (although it's never able to point at planets orbiting closer to the sun than it). How much of the year it's able to see an object depends on it's latitude (above/below the plane of the eccliptic); see [this chart](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard/jwst-target-viewing-constraints#JWSTTargetViewingConstraints-Targetobservability) for exact numbers.
- There are two small about-5° patches of sky straight "up" and "down" (aligned with the solar system's north and south poles) that it is able to see year-round; every other patch of sky is only visible for part of the year. These areas are called the "[Continuous Viewing Zones](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard#JWSTObservatoryCoordinateSystemandFieldofRegard-CVZContinuousviewingzone(CVZ))"

Comment: There’s a really good chart [here](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-characteristics/jwst-observatory-coordinate-system-and-field-of-regard/jwst-target-viewing-constraints), which is on the same site that you sourced a bunch of info from. It shows the number of observable days vs. viewing angle. There’s an even better plot I’ve seen somewhere, possibly even on this stack somewhere, that does the same thing but is a heat map of the full sky and shows how many days different zones are observable (and the fact that **every** area has at least *some* nonzero viewing time.

Comment: Thanks! So the shield does not "wrap around" in the sense that it is impossible to point the telescope away from the Sun. I do realize that this is not a serious handicap, because the astronomers only need to wait 3 months.

Comment: The continuous viewing zones are at the ecliptic poles, not quite the same as the Sun's north and south poles. The Sun's rotation is irrelevant to the geometry here: the Earth's orbit plane is the determining factor.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if the limited viewing area at any given time is a problem or not depends on what the observation target is.  For many observations you're right that it won't matter much because they're not time sensitive; but anything that is (ie transient phenomena like supernovas, neutron star mergers, interstellar comets, etc) will have a significant chance of not being observable by Webb while they're occurring.

Comment: Very true, @Dan. It will be sad if we miss the chance to record something spectacular because of that. If I did the math right, a bit less than 40 per cent of the sky can be viewed at any given instant of time, so the risk is there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  To be fair, that's similar to the Hubble, which *always* has ~50% of the sky blocked by the Earth.  In addition, it can't be pointed within 50° of the Sun, which blocks out an additional 0–18% of the sky depending on whether the Hubble is on the night side or the day side of the Earth.

Comment: A fair point @MichaelSeifert At least the Hubble would be on the other side of the Earth soon enough. It's late here, I may be getting a cold, and I cannot wrap my head around it. That won't help with targets near the Sun, but...

Comment: I suspect I'm being dense, but I'm having trouble understanding how the telescope can ever point directly in the anti-sun direction. Is it because the anti-sun direction in summer is 90deg from the sun (in/out of the page) in autumn/spring?

Comment: @craq yeah its complex.  The scope can aim 360 degrees tangentially to its orbit.  After 3 months (25% of a solar orbit), it has gone another 90 degrees around the sun, and that 360 degree view has turned sideways 90 degrees.   So **within 90 days, the camera can see everything** excluding the sun itself and near-sun objects and anything inside the solar orbit of Earth.   So patience is needed.

Comment: @criggie I believe it needs to travel about 170 degrees in the orbit to view all objects. The 85 deg limit in prograde direction needs to...process(?) to reach the retrograde 85 deg limit.

Comment: @Prometheus2508 ahh good point.  I looked at "360 degree rotation around Sun line" and didn't account for it not pointing 90 degrees to that line (like a wheel on an axle)

Comment: @Criggie Well we waited 10 years for it to launch, what's another .25 years to see a section of sky? :)

Comment: @Criggie Also, I'd say it's not the orbit of the Earth, but the orbit of the Earth Sun L2 that is out of scope.

Comment: Why cannot it point outward? Why the 45° limit? It seems a weird restriction...

Comment: @am70 the telescope is fixed to the sunshield; they have to rotate the whole thing as a unit. If they rotated it to point straight away from the sun, then the sun would hit the back of the mirror and instruments, and that would be bad. The 45° limit is as far as they can rotate it while keeping all the telescope parts still in the shadow of the sunshield.

Comment: Thanks. Still this is weird... they could have added a gimbal, so that the telescope azimuth could be changed wrt the sunshield. In any case they do have a gimbal to the earth-pointed gimbal

Comment: For a fixed interface between the telescope and sunshield, the current "side-pointing" orientation has two advantages I can see. First, it allows for more area to be viewed for the given sun shield size compared to an "outward" telescope; second, it allows for a larger mirror for the given launch vehicle (the mirror sits vertically in the fairing rather than across. Gimbling the telescope would provide yet another mode of failure and place additional loading on the attitude control to keep the sunshield "still" while the telescope moved.

Answer (score 10):

There are restrictions not only in direction but also in distance.

The JWST is sensitive to wavelengths from 0.6 to 28 µm. Any very early object very far away with a red shift to longer wavelengths above 28 µm could not be observed by the JWST.

Comment: Stuff behind the galactic center is probably also impossible to see.

Answer (score 7):

The JWST can aim from 85 degrees to 135 degrees along the orbital plane. 0 degrees is toward the sun and 90 degrees is tangent to the orbital ellipse. This keeps the Sun and Earth in the angle presented by the sunshield no matter the pointing angle. At any point in time, the JWST can only image something that lies within this field - of course, things outside that must wait until the telescope's orbit brings it into view.

The telescope would need to rotate on the axis defined by a vector from the Sun through the Earth to view anything "above" or "below" the ecliptic. I am assuming there is no problem to accomplishing this.

Comment: How does the field-of-view play into this? If I understand correctly, I think some area more-or-less shaped like an hourglass, centered on the Sun and aligned with the axis out of the ecliptic plane, is out-of-view. If only I could draw well...

Comment: @Ludo I think I understand what you're describing, but believe it's wrong. JWST doesn't aim outward, but sideways from the a line drawn from the sun to L2. 

https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/files/97976947/97976951/1/1596073033309/Fig3_JWST-side-view_coordinates_x1200px.png

It rotates fully on the sun line, making a ring of observable angles at any point in the orbit. Swinging that ring around the orbit, it can look at just about anything. It can't see a cone-shaped region defined by the Earth-Sun L2 orbit and forming two symmetric cones with a 5 degree pitch above and below the ecliptic.

Comment: @ Prometheus ---- can you clarify " It can't see a cone-shaped region defined by the Earth-Sun L2 orbit and forming two symmetric cones with a 5 degree pitch above and below the ecliptic." ?  I understand JWST can aim at any point on the celestial sphere over a 6 month half-orbit

Comment: @Prometheus2508 Yes, you're right; thinking more about it it's indeed not an hourglass-like thing. Not sure what the shape of the unobservable space does look like though. I don't think it's a sphere centered on the sun, but not certain.

Comment: @Woody It's the volume of space the telescope can't look at (not accounting for any minimum focusing distance). Draw the Earth-Sun L2 orbit, draw a line tangent to that ellipse at some arbitrary point. That line is the 90 deg look angle for JWST frame of reference. Its sunshield is designed to support a minimum look angle of 85 deg, so draw that line, then imagine rotating it about the L2 point. Anything sun-side of that surface it can't see from that point. Consider how that surface moves across all orbital points. Any point that never falls anti-sun of that surface is unobservable.

Comment: @Prometheus2508 --- You're right. As well, the telescope is not articulated with the shield, so it can't look anti-sunward more than 45* or the Sun would fry its butt. So, at any given time JWST can only view about a third of the celestial sphere. But 3 months later, it is 90* around in its orbit and has a whole new piece of sky to look at.

Comment: "The telescope would need to rotate on the axis defined by a vector from the Sun through the Earth to view anything "above" or "below" the ecliptic." I would think the axis would be tangent to the orbit.

Comment: @Accumulation The axis of rotation is the axis that stays fixed. If it rotated about an axis tangent to the orbit, it would rotate the sunshield out of solar coverage.